# Two files combination

Tags: python, file

The first file looks something like this:

```
writing
writing
writing 
writing
eating
eating 
eating
doing
doing
doing
...
```

The second file looks this way:

```
writing write wrote written
eating eat ate
doing do does done
...
```

So basically, I need to add words (word by word) from the second file to each line of a first file (sequentially one word per line) and save it in a third file which would look like this:

```
writing writing
writing write
writing wrote
writing written
eating eating
eating eat
eating ate
doing doing
doing do
doing does
doing done
...
```

I tried this code but it does not do the job:

```
infile = open("first.txt", 'r') # open file for reading
infile2 = open("second.txt", 'r') # open file for reading
outfile = open("third.txt","w") # open file for writing

line = infile.readline()
line2 = infile2.readline()      # Invokes readline() method on file
while line:
    outfile.write(line.strip(' ')+line2.strip("\n")+'\n')
    line = infile.readline()
    line2 = infile2.readline()

infile.close()
outfile.close()
infile2.close()
```

Comment: In what way does it "not do the job"? What's different between the actual and desired outputs?

Comment: *"it does not do the job"* is a profoundly unhelpful problem statement. What **does** it do, then? Unexpected output (provide actual output and compare explicitly with what you expected)? Errors (provide full traceback)?

Comment: Also, as a hint: look up the `zip` function. You can write that whole mess as `for line1, line2 in zip(infile1, infile2):`. (Not that I think you want that logic anyway… but it's hard to tell what you want, and that's the logic you wrote.)

Comment: Anyway, if you think about the functions you're calling, there's no way they could do what you want. If `infile.readline()` returns `'working\n'`, what's going to happen when you call `strip(' ')` on it? More importantly, if you want to iterate over all of the words in `line`, how is `strip("\n")` going to help you do that?

Comment: Zip will not work because infile2 has less lines than infile1. For example infile1 has 4 lines for write and infile2 has only one.

Comment: @semptic: As I said in my comment, I don't think the logic he's trying to write is the logic he wants, but that's the logic he's trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

To put your two files together I would read both completely and split them in different ways to get your words and then put them together.

Load the first file. In the first file there are one word per line, so read each line and store it into a list:

```
words_first = []
with open('first.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words_first.append(line)
```

Load the second file. The second file has multiple words per line and multiple lines, so read each line and split it into words and store it into a list:

```
words_second = []
with open('second.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words_second.extend(line.split(" "))
```

Store into the new file. Now you have two list of words, so use zip to pack them together and store them into the file:

```
with open('third.txt', 'w') as f:
    for first, second in zip(words_first, words_second):
        f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(first, second))
```

This version utilizes `split()` (which splits all white space (newlines and spaces)), so you can split the complete files and get a list of all words separated by newlines and spaces:

```
def get_words(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return f.read().split()

with open('third.txt', 'w') as f:
    for first, second in zip(get_words("first.txt"), get_words("second.txt")):
        f.write("{0} {1}".format(first, second))
```

Comment: `f.read().split()` will work to get a list of words for both input files.

Comment: You are right. But I think this solution explains more what happens and help Zvone Peran to understand what he is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even need the first file?

```
infile2 = open('second.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('third.txt', 'w')
for line in infile2:
    words = line.split()
    outfile.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % (words[0], w) for w in words) + '\n')
outfile.close()
infile2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a first file because I thought it would be easier to do the task. I am still a beginer in Python so I don't know yet many of built-in functions.